"GdmSession: no session desktop files installed" after rebooting
I suspended my desktop machine with 24.04 yesterday and found that the lock screen did not react to input. After rebooting it failed to start up the GUI.
This is what I found in the logs:
$ journalctl --unit gdm.service --no-pager 
May 31 09:34:13 za31 gdm3[3913]: Gdm: GdmSession: no session desktop files installed, aborting...


Note: I'm using the TPM-FDE installation variant.

I installed the ubuntu-session package, restarted gnome and then I was able to login again.
sudo apt install ubuntu-session
sudo systemctl restart gdm.service

The first results I found from over 10 years ago for this problem suggested the gnome-session package, if that is your desktop of choice then you have to install that or any applicable other session that you need.

You're life saver!

Well this is awkward and a warning sign that I'm not the only one and we seem to have a serious bug in Ubuntu. Thanks for confirming.

This just happened to me. Thank you so much for identifying the fix.

Had this issue with Ubuntu 24.04. Turns out that I installed fuse which removed ubuntu-session. All is well till you reboot and cant get paste the stop plymouth start gdm part of boot.

CTRL-ALT-F2
login
sudo apt remove fuse
sudo apt install ubuntu-session
reboot

If you do need fuse install fuse3
apt install fuse3
No clue why fuse2 is still available and is the default for apt install fuse as it definitely breaks s$*t.  Hope this helps.

That could have been the cause since I installed libfuse2 for Appimage support.

Thanks so much @james-dunn-errorcode67, that would have taken me forever to figure out.
